# SecondaryLoop instead of SwingWorker?

Tags: java, swing, java-7, swingworker, secondaryloop

From the documentation for [SecondaryLoop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html), it is not clear when you should use this new feature instead of a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), a few examples of interesting cases would be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intent of SecondaryLoop is basically the same as SwingWorker.  However, using SecondaryLoop can be less hairy than chaining together multiple SwingWorkers.

Take a look at [Hidden Java 7 Features – SecondaryLoop](https://web.archive.org/web/20151104044220/http://sellmic.com/blog/2012/02/29/hidden-java-7-features-secondaryloop/) for a detailed explanation & example.