# SwingWorker for Both Output & Work, or 1 Each?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, secondaryloop

Currently I always create a `SwingWorker` to do my actual work, and another to process the output via a `PipedReader`.

I'd love to combine the two, but I just don't see an easy way to do it, in my situation.

Given that I:

1. Have a pre-made object that does work (`converter`, in this case)
2. Want to routinely display updates on `converter`'s progress to the GUI
3. Receive an object when `converter` finishes its task and returns.

Is there a way to do this without two SwingWorkers?

Edit:  Note that making `converter` extend `SwingWorker` is not an option.

Edit 2:  In response to comment below.  This is part of a larger GUI application, processing large chunks of data (in the form of txt) and informing the user what is wrong, or what has been decided.

Example Code (purely illustrative, not used):

```
//SwingWorker 1
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() {

   outputWorker.useInStream(new PipedReader(outStream));
   outputWorker.execute();
   converter.usePipedWriter(outStream);
   Output object2=converter.Convert(object1);

}

//SwingWorker 2
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() {

   while(inStream.hasNext()) {
      publish(inStream.next());
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a swingWorker at all? Is this touching any UI?

Comment: @user1291492 yes it is.  Processing 30 mb text files, and letting the user  see what  decisions are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JDK7, you might consider using [SecondaryLoop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html) instead of chaining together multiple SwingWorker instances.

SecondaryLoop essentially allows you to wait for a background thread (or series of threads) to complete without blocking the EDT, similar to SwingWorker.  It is may not be suitable as a replacement for SwingWorker in every case, however based on the description of your problem it sounds like this is something you might be able to use.

For more discussion on this topic, please take a look related question, "[SecondaryLoop instead of SwingWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196809/secondaryloop-instead-of-swingworker/10197838#10197838)
"

Comment: Thank you! That looks like a good solution.  I will try implementing it

Answer (score 2):

not an answer to your question if use one or two `SwingWorker`, I want to complicating these things ...

- I'd suggest to look at [Executor that invoke SwingWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6174462/714968) and the same code with real [visualisations / output to the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6186188/714968)
- `Executor` doesn't care somhow about `SwingWorkers` lifecycle and vice versa

> @user1291492 Processing 30 mb text files

- you have to [listening for exception(s) from methods `get()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa) , expecially read [answer by @trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7054627/714968)
- you have to (`Processing 30 mb text files`) to implementing some `Batch`, for example every 10loops you publish data to the GUI, then output to the GUI will be immediatelly
- during `Batch` is possible to stop the current thread by S`wingWorker#cancel();`